# PDF.js does not open pdf file android

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, pdf.js

I am trying to read local pdf file which is saved in Android download folder.
I created app and set everything like it should be and app reads pdf if it is saved in asset:

```
Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format("file:///android_asset/abc.pdf")));
```

But if I use:

```
Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format("file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/foo.pdf")));
```

nothing is showing.

I checked if file exist:

```
            string abc;
            if (File.Exists(string.Format("/storage/emulated/0/Download/foo.pdf")))
            {
                abc = "exist!!!!";
            }
            else
            {
                abc = "not exist!";
            }
```

and it confirmes file exist.

If i use OpenPdf project: https://github.com/acaliaro/OpenPdf
then it can open file saved in Download folder.
What am I doing wrong? Different Android version? Api level? I compared OpenPdf project with my project, everything seems to be ok.

Permisions are set too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Did you add this code `Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;`

Comment: yes, everything is set up

Answer (score 1):

For everybody who has similar issue:
Solution is very trivial.
Apart from permissions adjusted in AndroidManifest.xml I had to go to phone aplications settings and turn on memory permission manualy.

Everything is working now.